Sample C# Code to Write to Azure Service Bus fails with System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Put token failed. status-code: 401,
When I create an azure service bus, this Microsoft sample C# code to write to the queue works. I know it works because I can read the queue with this code.
However, when I add an azure function to read the queue, the above sample code to write to the queue fails with this stack trace:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature..
For troubleshooting information, see 
https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.

When I look at that link (https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot) in the stack trace It says

An UnauthorizedAccessException indicates that the provided credentials do not allow for the requested action to be performed. The Message property contains details about the failure.

I cannot find the message property.
I know the service bus and the attached azure function reading the queue work because I can write to the service bus queue with the Service bus Explorer and see my azure function log entries.
Please help me enhance the above code (see the first link) to send a message to the service bus when the azure function is reading the queue message successfully.
Thanks
Siegfried

It would be helpful to see how you're initializing the client.  The message would seem that the shared key or SAS token that you're passing when you create the client is malformed.  A connection is not established until a service operation is requested, so you wouldn't see an auth failure like this until you invoke one.   The Message in this context is the Message property of the exception:  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.exception.message

Shucks, I'm having trouble reproducing the problem.  I will try again.

I've tried many times and I cannot reproduce the problem.
We can consider this resolved.
